# Nested mapped types in TypeScript

Tags: typescript

I have this type:

```js
type Requests = {
  "/endpoint": {
    POST: {
      body: any
      response: any
    }
    // ...
  }
  // ...
}
```

I want to map `response` to another value, but I get an error in vscode:

```js
export type API = {
  [route in keyof Requests]: {
    [method in keyof Requests[route]]: {
      body: Requests[route][method]["body"] //  Type '"body"' cannot be used to index type 'Requests[route][method]'
      response: Requests[route][method]["response"] | { error: any } //  Type '"request"' cannot be used to index type 'Requests[route][method]'
    }
  }
}
```

Is there any way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should do what you want

```
type Requests = {
    "/endpoint": {
    POST: {
        body: string
        response: number
    }
    // ...
    },

}


export type API = {
    [route in keyof Requests]: {
        [method in keyof Requests[route]]: {
        body: Requests[route][method] extends { body: infer R } ? R : never
        response: (Requests[route][method] extends { response: infer R } ? R : never) | { error: any }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow, didn't know about the `infer` keyword at all. Thanks for this, it should be helpful for many related problems like this.

Comment: In that case, let me mention that there's a common trick to using the infer keyword, which isn't especially documented anywhere. The inference is much more capable in the context of functions so often with complicated types it helps to add in an auxiliary function type, so that for instance if I want to get the type of the tail of a tuple, I can do like so.

`type S<T extends any[]> = ((...args: T) => any) extends ((s: any, ...rest: infer R) => any) ? R : []`

`type W = S<[1, "it", "gets", "the", "rest"]>`

Answer (score -1):

It appears typescript can't really generalize about any key that might be in that type, even though the list is finite and known. But it's easy to help it out.

If you specify the general format for the type:

```
type RequestsFormat = Record<string, { [key: string]: { body: any, response: any } }>
```

And then extend that:

```
interface Requests extends RequestsFormat {
  "/endpoint": {
    POST: {
      body: any
      response: any
    }
  }
}
```

Then typescript can figure out the rest.

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAShCOBXCBnYKBiB7ATgWwENgoBeWCAY1wBMAeNHASwDsBzAGigG8oBtAawggAXFAYtWAXVE8ARlmoioBZiE45UYLMxQRRKkFAC+xgHwAocy2AQcAMwIVocJKnRQIADxvNqKcq5omLiExFzmUFAARAD0EL5a1lEyEZFQAAoA8gDKACopaWnyivqqqYUaKFo6esplhUapjY3moJBQAIKkUIIgWHYByEGWXlo4xG3QHekAkt3hkbw4WIg2UCw9Qv2DbijS3OV8eBDAABYK68ybfQMuQ+hLKzaS+wuFUHZYWKJ3u4+rEEkvGOZwUkkOkWKSl+QX+z2BJ3O1CBAHIoSjJFAYjEoIBeDcAFXtQXLgaAoqJQqIoqAUFTMLDEWTQRC6ahQYBYS7ULxsklQFEwh7LAFAkFIyQoiFQSrVXQ-BD3FBwwEI0HI3hRaXaXRRTEAH24HhwyxwpUMJmxeMJxPaZI0gWAlOptPpUEZUGZEFZ7M53MmfIFiqF8NFYIlDSa5iMQA)

Comment: This fixes the error, but widens the `keyof` type for `Requests` to `string`. e.g. a type of `Requests["asdf"]` would not throw an error, due to the `Record<string, ...>` type.